# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/templaterenderer/TemplateRenderer while updating JIRA maven plugin

Tags: maven, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

When I try to update jira plugin, the problem java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/templaterenderer/TemplateRenderer is occured. 
This plugin uses service which I put to

```
/opt/jira/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes and
/opt/jira/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib
```

directories.

So, I do next steps:
1) Remove myOldPlugin from Add-ons
2) Remove myOldService from Services in JIRA console
3) Remove myOldService.jar file from

```
/opt/jira/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes and
/opt/jira/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib
```

4) Install myNewPlugin to Add-ons

and got this error:

```
 [atlassian.plugin.loaders.ScanningPluginLoader] Because of the following exception:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/templaterenderer/TemplateRenderer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Unknown Source)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.templaterenderer.TemplateRenderer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 95 more
```

This error is absent if I restart JIRA before installing myNewPlugin but this impossible for working process.
I suppose this problem occured because of myService.jar cause before we have it we could restart plugin without any problems.
So I need to update plugin and service without restarting JIRA

Please, help.

Comment: I've just found this resolve: To resolve this, the caches have to be cleared. To do so, follow these steps :
Shut down JIRA.
Delete the following directories:
$JIRA_HOME/plugins/.bundled_plugins
$JIRA_HOME/plugins/.osgi_plugins
(info) These are temporary files and folders and will be recreated when JIRA starts.
But this is not what I want - I need update plugin without restarting jira every time. Please help somebody

Answer (score 2):

If you would like update your Jira plugin without restart Jira application, please

- First update your **Atlassian Plugin SDK** to latest version here https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?q=sdk (please find appropriate package for your  OS) .
- The next step is read documentation of **Atlassian QuickReload**, it is a silver bullet to make magic happen